# How can an "architectural motif" be extracted from a trained MLP?

Tags: neural-networks, papers, neural-architecture-search

I am trying to reproduce the paper [Synthetic Petri Dish: A novel surrogate model for Rapid Architecture Search](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2005.13092.pdf). In the paper, the authors try to reduce the architecture of an MLP model trained on MNIST (2 layers - 100 neurons) by initializing a **motif network** from it, that is, 2 layers, 1 neuron each, and extracting the sigmoid function. I have been searching a lot, but I have not found the answer of how can someone extract an 'architectural motif' from a **trained** neural network.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to AI SE. Have you already looked into https://github.com/uber-research/Synthetic-Petri-Dish? If you find the answer in this Github repo or somewhere else, feel free to write a formal answer below to your own question ;)

Comment: @nbro Hello, thanks for welcoming me. Indeed I did but unfortunately they did not include the motif extraction part in their code. What they do only is display the motif training points - which they define in their paper as tuple of slope values and validation accuracy.

Comment: Maybe the best thing to do is open an issue in the issue tracker of that repo, if nobody provides an answer meanwhile.